# JHipster new application test fail on ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jhipster

I have a created a new application JHipster and without any modification, I am not able to package it.

Here is my .yo-rc.json

```
 {
 "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
    "packageName": "testbug",
    "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "5.1.0",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "testBugJhipster",
    "packageName": "testbug",
    "packageFolder": "testbug",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": "spring-websocket",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Memory",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": "kafka",
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": true,
    "jwtSecretKey": "a1643dc27d4bad4c20782e29fe5491fc3ecdf5e5",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "testFrameworks": [
    "gatling",
    "cucumber",
    "protractor"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
    "en",
    "fr"
    ]
}
}
```

To package, I use

```
./mvnw -Pprod package
```

At first, I had this error :

```
[INFO] Running 'yarn run webpack:test' in /home/korrident/testBugJhipster
[INFO] yarn run v1.6.0
[INFO] $ yarn run test
[INFO] $ yarn run lint && jest --coverage --logHeapUsage -w=2 --config src/test/javascript/jest.conf.js
[INFO] $ tslint --project tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/**'
[ERROR] No valid rules have been specified
[ERROR] FAIL src/test/javascript/spec/app/shared/login/login.component.spec.ts
[ERROR]   ● Test suite failed to run
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]     SecurityError: localStorage is not available for opaque origins
[ERROR]       
[ERROR]       at Window.get localStorage [as localStorage] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:257:15)
[ERROR]           at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
[ERROR]
```

based on this SO : 
[client side tests fail using jhipster 5.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642253/client-side-tests-fail-using-jhipster-5-1-0/51643737#51643737)

I added at the end of src/test/javascript/jest.conf.js

```
testEnvironment: "node",
testURL: "http://localhost/"
```

But now, I have this error

```
[INFO] $ yarn run test
[INFO] $ yarn run lint && jest --coverage --logHeapUsage -w=2 --config src/test/javascript/jest.conf.js
[INFO] $ tslint --project tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/**'
[ERROR] No valid rules have been specified
[ERROR] FAIL src/test/javascript/spec/app/admin/health/health.component.spec.ts
[ERROR]   ● Test suite failed to run
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]     ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
[ERROR]       
[ERROR]       at patchXHR (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2926:39)
[ERROR]       at node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2919:5
[ERROR]       at Function.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.__load_patch (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:84:33)
[ERROR]       at node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2917:6
[ERROR]       at Object.<anonymous>.FUNCTION (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:9:65)
[ERROR]       at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:12:2)
[ERROR]       at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setupJest.js:5:1)
[ERROR]
```

Except jest.conf.js, git diff show no other changes from the init commit.

I tried to install xmlhttprequest@^1.8.0 but no change in jest result.

This question is not urgent because I can disable the test, but I can't allow it for too long.

Comment: You set the env to node, but XMLHttpRequest isn't a part of node. If you're writing browser code, test it as such.

Comment: Change it to `testEnvironment: 'jsdom'`. Adding `testURL: 'http://localhost'` should be enough to fix the first error. This is all related to a [bug in Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6766) which was discovered by a [minor release update of jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2304).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @jared-smith for solving it.

Correct configuration in src/test/javascript/jest.conf.js

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/src/test/javascript/jest.ts',
    coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/target/test-results/',
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsConfigFile: 'tsconfig.json'
        },
        __TRANSFORM_HTML__: true
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        'app/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/main/webapp/app/$1'
    },
    reporters: [
        'default',
        [ 'jest-junit', { output: './target/test-results/jest/TESTS-results.xml' } ]
    ],
    testResultsProcessor: 'jest-sonar-reporter',
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@angular/common/locales)'],
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/test/javascript/spec/**/+(*.)+(spec.ts)'],
    rootDir: '../../../',

    //Path generated code
    //To correct SecurityError: localStorage
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    testURL: "http://localhost/"
};
```

Packaging is now working fine.
(Shouldn't this configuration be commited in jhipster ?)